# redirect to next/route action, not the last after user login/registration symfony security

Tags: php, symfony, security, redirect, fosuserbundle

I have a form like this in a view:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('process_route'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}
  {#  some other fields #}
  {{ form_row(form.placeOrder) }}
  {{ form_row(form.saveOrder) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

As you can see I have two submit button, but it's not a problem, I use the symfony method:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ... do something

    // the save_and_add button was clicked
    if ($form->get('placeOrder')->isClicked()) {
        // probably redirect to the add page again
    }

    // redirect to the show page for the just submitted item
}
```

As you can see my form have a **specific** action process route named `'process_route'`. 
When I submit the form, regardless the submit button user clicked, I checked if user is connect or not with the `security.context`.

If user is connected, I redirect on the route he called when clicking on one the two submit buttons.

But it user is not connected I redirect first on `user registration` (if it's not register yet) or user log in form.

Once the user have registered or logged in, I need to redirect to the route he asked first when he clicked on one of the two submit buttons.

In fact, the redirection works well, except the redirection is carried out on **last requested** action, *e-g* on **the process route form action** (here `'process_route'`), and I need to redirect to the next step, not to the last one.

In my security.yml, I have this:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: custom
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
                use_referer : true
```

How can I proceed to manage the redirection following the user required action by clicking on one of the two submit button form, and not to the last action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `referer` manually in the request.

Try to do this from your controller directly, e.g. :

```
if ($form->get('placeOrder')->isClicked()) {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $request->headers->set('referer', $this->generateUrl('expected_route'));
}
```

My doubt is the request is not updated on the next.
In this case, look for a [`RequestListener`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types) and find a way to set the good `referer` depending on conditions.

**Update**

For the login, override the default login form add the following field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.headers.get('referer') }}" />
```

Don't forget to set the referer manually from your controller in all cases.

**Update 2**

Because the `referer` is not correctly updated in the login form, I'll try to give you a quick alternative.

If I understood correctly, you are manually rendering the login form from your controller.

At the moment of you render the form, pass an additional parameter to your view :

```
return $this->render('UserBundle:Security:login.html.twig, array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    // ...
    '_target_path' => $this->generateUrl('expected_referer'), // Defined from your condition depending on button clicked
);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly with the user **registration** form (a custom registration form who embed the fos_user_registration). But not for the Login form. For the logIn form I am using the `fos_user_registration` form of `FOSUserBundle`

Comment: @french_dev Can you please show me your login method ? Add it in your question or share me a [gist](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: in fact the login method is as simple as the native `fos_user_login` form. e-g in my controller, after submit the form `if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')` then I display the login form from FOSUserBundle. So my login method is the FOSUser login method.
I need to change the redirection only that form. Else, I have to keep the native behavior of FOSUserbundle.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still not work. I make a `{{ dump(app.request) }}` in the login form in order to be sure. But the **headers** `referer` is still the form process route.

Comment: thank you for all your suggestion, I found a way/solution by myself creating a service container. Don't hesitate to tell me if it's bad or good. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I see your point of view in your update, i will try this as soon as I can and validate it if it works ! thank you... again ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but I would like to be sure that it is a best practice.

Notice that this redirection have to be execute only at a specific moment in the application and not in all the website. So I decided to create a service listener.

In fact, the redirection have to be executed when the session have a specific entity object that I named êntity.

Fist, this is the declaration of the service in `app/config/services.yml`:

```
# apply the redirect response for connected user when and only where $isEntitySession !=null
    # to recover the current request in a service we need to set the scope argument, then call the symfony service container where $request is stored
    # just understand that it is not recommanded (bad structure and mad practice) to apply directly the request in service without service container
    my_bundle.login_listener:
        class: MySpace\MyBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin  }
        scope: request
        arguments: ["@router","@security.context","@event_dispatcher","@service_container"]
```

Then this is the LoginListener.php in `MySpace/MyBundle/EventListener/LoginListener.php`:

```
<?php

namespace MySpace\MyBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoginListener
{
  protected $router;
  protected $security;
  protected $dispatcher;
  protected $container;

  public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, ContainerInterface $container)
  {
      $this->router = $router;
      $this->security = $security;
      $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
      $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
  {
      $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, array($this, 'onKernelResponse'));
  }

  public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
  {
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    $session = $this->container->get('session');

    $isEntitySession = $session->get('entity_form') != null;

    if($isEntitySession && $request->isMethod('POST') ) {
      $entity = $session->get('entity_form');
    }

    if(isset($entity)) {

      if ($entity->getState() == 'true') { //here the state is a bool, don't search anymore about this, it's just an entity object relation set to true or false. Following the state, I return a different view.

        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('place_order_route'));

      } else {

        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('save_order_route'));
      }

      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
  }
}
```

All the comment in the `services.yml` could help you to understand the apply of Service container. The symfony doc tell you not to use Request directly in a service declaration. Don't hesitate to tell me if the right thing to do or not.

Note that I used the security.context, in fact I would like to use it by recover user data, but as the purpose here, no need to use it, so we could remove this `argument` and the variable in the `__construct()`.

to find out which button was clicked , I play with the Entity `getState()` method. Indeed, following this state, the redirection is not the same.

Comment: I believed you cannot make the redirection on the good route without know which button is clicked, otherwise I would use an EventListener directly ^^ It's a pity. You solution is good, especially if it fits your need :)

Comment: @chalasr  see my edit, the `getState()` method is a way to know where the redirection have to be apply.

Comment: What I mean is that with this information, my first answer would looks like yours. Your solution is, for me, cleaner than an additional step in controller (i.e. your `process_route`). More reusable.